# How to remove items from ArrayAdapter when an EditText is changed?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to implement a way to remove items from a ListView when text is added to an EditText, sort of like an auto complete.

I have created the following ArrayAdapter to test simply:

```
mListViewItem; // My ListView
mEditTextItem; // My EditText

String[] arr = new String[]{"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item_medication, arr);
mListViewItem.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now, I added an event handler to handle text changes. For now, all I want to do is remove items that do not contain the input of the EditText. For this example, if I type "O", then items 'Three' and 'Five' should be removed. I have tried this:

```
mEditTextItem.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
       for(int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++){
          if(!adapter.getItem(i).contains(s)){
             adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(i));
          }
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

But I don't know how to code the 'remove' function to remove necessary items, as this gives me an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I don't know how to code the 'remove' function to remove necessary
>   items, as this gives me an UnsupportedOperationException

If you pass an array as the data for an `ArrayAdapter` that array will be transformed into an unchangeable list(this mean you can't change the size of the list by adding or removing items from it). This is what the adapter is trying to do when using `remove()` and it obviously fails with that exception.

The most simply solution is to use a normal list(like `ArrayList`) with the data instead of that array:

```
String[] arr = new String[]{"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"};
List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String item : arr) {
     data.add(item);
}
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item_medication, data);
mListViewItem.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you. I completely overlooked the immutability of an array.

Comment: Is there a way to just remove items from the listview? How can I work backwards to see the items again when I backspace? Is that a different question altogether?

Comment: @McAdam331 What you're looking for is the `Filterable` interface which most adapter implementation use. This is used to filter the content of the adapter(and also revert stuff). I would advise you to extend the `BaseAdapter` class and implement the adapter completely along with the filter you want.

Comment: I will look into that, thanks. I don't plan on keeping an adapter like this for my actual application but wanted to keep the question simple.